# What's the correct syntax for a named arrow function registered as callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, syntax, arrow-functions

I'm having trouble understanding how could I replace a function declaration that is registered as a callback. This snippet works as intended:

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const url = require('url');
const ct = { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' };

http.createServer((req, res) => {

  let q = url.parse(req.url, true);
  if (q.pathname === "/") {
    fs.readFile('./index.html', renderIndex);
  }

function renderIndex(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.writeHead(200, ct);
    console.log("Rendering index");
    return res.end(data);
  }
}).listen(8080)
```

However, I was wondering if it were possible to refactor the `renderIndex` declaration into an arrow function.

I know from testing that a function expression wouldn't work. So this is not possible:

```
...
const renderIndex = function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.writeHead(200, ct);
    console.log("Rendering index");
    return res.end(data);
  }
...
```

And so neither is:

```
...
const renderIndex = (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.writeHead(200, ct);
    console.log("Rendering index");
    return res.end(data);
  }
...
```

But is there a valid arrow function syntax that would enable me to register `renderIndex` as a callback in `fs.readFile('./index.html', renderIndex);`... perhaps refactoring that line as well?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried moving the function expression definition before the line where the function is used? I think that will work, and I also think an arrow function defined before it's used will also work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you move the function definition before the line where it's used, it should work. Like this:

```js
http.createServer((req, res) => {

  const renderIndex = (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.writeHead(200, ct);
    console.log("Rendering index");
    return res.end(data);
  }

  let q = url.parse(req.url, true);
  if (q.pathname === "/") {
    fs.readFile('./index.html', renderIndex);
  }
}).listen(8080)
```

If it were my code, I would move the function definition outside of the containing function, completely, currying it so I can pass `res` to it before it's used as a callback:

```js
const renderIndex = res => (err, data) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  res.writeHead(200, ct);
  console.log("Rendering index");
  return res.end(data);
}

http.createServer((req, res) => {
  let q = url.parse(req.url, true);
  if (q.pathname === "/") {
    fs.readFile('./index.html', renderIndex(res));
  }
}).listen(8080)
```

Comment: All answers are good, but I'm marking this one as correct  since it not only answers the question, but aims to further the intended objective: have a cleaner code by moving the function outside the createServer block. I also wasn't aware of currying but it's a super interesting concept I'll make sure to research more. Thanks a lot for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

function definition hoisting occurs only for function declaration not for function expressions.

move the function expression above so that it is already defined before passing as callback

```
const renderIndex = (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.writeHead(200, ct);
    console.log("Rendering index");
    return res.end(data);
  }

 let q = url.parse(req.url, true);
  if (q.pathname === "/") {
    fs.readFile('./index.html', renderIndex);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript there is a thing called [function hoisting](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript), meanining that functions are automatically put at the top of the code.

So when you do:

```
http.createServer((req, res) => {

  let q = url.parse(req.url, true);
  if (q.pathname === "/") {
    fs.readFile('./index.html', renderIndex);
  }

  function renderIndex(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.writeHead(200, ct);
    console.log("Rendering index");
    return res.end(data);
  }
}).listen(8080)
```

Its the equivalent of

```
http.createServer((req, res) => {
 function renderIndex(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.writeHead(200, ct);
    console.log("Rendering index");
    return res.end(data);
  }

  let q = url.parse(req.url, true);
  if (q.pathname === "/") {
    fs.readFile('./index.html', renderIndex);
  }
}).listen(8080)
```

Note that the function is now at the top. When using const or let things are not hoisted so order starts to matter. You can't use a variable (const) that you haven't declared.

So like mentioned in other answers the solution is to move the const arrow function to the top.

Comment: I believe variables are also hoisted, isn't that right? So `When using const or let things are not hoisted so order starts to matter. You can't use a variable (const) that you haven't declared.` is only true for function expression... Not entirely sure about this, though

Comment: var and functions are hoisted, not let and const: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp